# reportviewer visible = false in page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, report-viewer2010

I have problem with the report viewer.If I set my report viewer as `visible=false` in page_load page on event button click, if i already set as `visible=true`, it still make the reportviewer `visible= false`. Can anyone help me with this problem? or is there any other solution..i have 2 reportviewer in a aspx page and i need one of it to be `visible=false` in page_load. here's the code..thank youuu

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDdlCountryValue();

            ReportViewer_TotalCountry.Visible = false;


        }

protected void btnViewReport_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ReportViewer_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry.LocalReport.Refresh();
            ReportViewer_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry.Visible = true;
            ReportViewer_TotalCountry.Visible = false;

    }

    protected void btn_AllCountry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ReportViewer_TotalCountry.LocalReport.Refresh();
            ReportViewer_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry.Visible = false;
            ReportViewer_TotalCountry.Visible = true;

    }
```

as you can see,when i click `btn_AllCountry_Click`, the 
`ReportViewer_TotalCountry.Visible = true`; ill remain visible=false :(

help me..i'm new to this reporting :'(

---

```
 <div>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
     InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" SizeToReportContent="True" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 6WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" >
        <LocalReport ReportPath="RDLC\TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry_Report.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry" 
                    Name="TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry_DataSet" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry" 
        runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="IMP_report.ttfsListTableAdapters.TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountryTableAdapter">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList_Country" Name="CountryName" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</div>
<div id="TotalCountry" align="center" >
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_TotalCountry" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
  WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" SizeToReportContent="True" >
    <LocalReport ReportPath="RDLC\TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry_Report.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource_ttfsSummaryTotalCountry" 
                Name="TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry_DataSet" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource_ttfsSummaryTotalCountry" 
    runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectMethod="GetData" 
    TypeName="IMP_report.ttfsListTableAdapters.TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountryTotalTableAdapter">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
</div>
```

Comment: is this the only place where ReportViewer_TotalCountry's visibility is set?

Comment: yes, in report viewer propeties, i do not set as visible=false, means the default which is visble=true..thanks

Comment: show me your `HTML` code plz,,,I want to see that how you are using your `ReportViewer` so plz update your `html` code of these two `ReportViewer`.thanks

Comment: @Doherty dear plz check my logic.

Answer (score 2):

On few reports I use :

`rptViewer.ShowReportBody = false;` on `Page_Load`

and

`rptViewer.ShowReportBody = true;` on `button_click`.

I think it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,but i have try it before.but still give the same results. i just solve this problem by redirect to another report page each time the button is clicked.means one report viewer per one page.silly isn't it? :p

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this type of problem, hope you like, Instead of setting `Visibility` of `ReportViewer`. Try to set `Visibility` of your `Div` control like

```
<div id="TotalSummary" runat="server" >
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_TTFSSummaryBasedOnCountry" runat="server">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
<div id="TotalCountry" align="center" runat="server" >
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_TotalCountry" runat="server" >
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

When you want to set Any of `ReportViewer Visibility` to `True` or `False` then instead of this try to set `Div` Visibility.

Note: `Not forget to use runat="server" under div tag`.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Comment: oh, i've tried that before..when you set the visibility in div,the div will control the visibility but not in this report viewer case, for example,if i set in the div visible=true, and in page_load visible=false, on button click even !ispostback=true, its will visible=false..but all the label or button inside the div will visible=true..sigh~~thats always keep me wonder why.. :( i think that report viewer inside page load is a special case,means that if it's set as visible=false in page_load,it will always be visible=false even out of postback. any idea??thanks anyway ^.^

Comment: ok just tell me that when your page will run first time then you want to show which report first and if you are using `div` technique then no need to set `visible = false` to the controls you are using inside `div`,,just need to set only `div` visible property.

Comment: you mean just set visibility of the div but not the visibility report viewer right?yes @rahul i've done that..still does not work. i've google for the problems but still doesnt solve this issue..

Comment: ok just tell me that when your page will run first time then you want to show which report first.

Comment: sorry,i dont understand what you mean :p @rahul

Comment: yes,i want to show certain report in first time page run.if i have two reports,then on first time run i just want to show one report only.